# Special status for questions with self-answers

Tags: feature-request, questions, voting, down-votes, self-answer

I would like others' opinion on removing the up/down vote for the question on a question with a self-answer. We should leave the up/downvote for the answer though, and also automatically mark it as answer. And instead of displaying the question's score when browsing, display the answer instead.

I ask this because of drive-by or lazy users, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44836697/6554121 ([screenshot for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHST3.png)).

I posted this with a self-answer. And I wouldn't mind getting a downvote on the answer if it was bad and explained why, but a down vote on the question seems like they were just browsing, saw the lack of code/explanation and just downvoted without any other investigation and move on.

I feel like this would really discourage other people from sharing their own self-answered questions if people were to basically just have a glimpse and downvote without any further investigation.

Thoughts?

Comment: @DonaldDuck from the tag and the comments on the answer I think they mean self answers/blog overflow.

Comment: @Catija yeah, that's what I meant, I put it in brackets now, probably won't clear much up though.

Comment: Why bother? Get rid of "Q&A". It's clearly confusing everyone and it's not the term we use here.

Comment: @Catija I've approved Donald Duck's edit, hopefully it'll clear up confusion

Comment: I've got self answered questions where I've accepted another user's answer. An answer shouldn't be automatically accepted.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards if you like the new answer, then change it. Not like it prevents it

Answer (score 12):

If a question is bad, it deserves a downvote. It does not matter who answered it.

> How do I use datatables server-side with PHP as demonstrated here: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

This is not even a question that can be understood without visiting another site. Qualifies to be closed as "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: then what about this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816057/how-do-i-setup-live-code-reload-with-featherjs I'm quite happy to take my question an answer down, since I'll have a copy of my knowledge anyway, it's really stackoverflow's loss more than mine.

Comment: I guess there's no longer any encouragement to post Q&A then. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @A.Lau When you say "q&a" do you mean self answers? Everything on SE is "q&a", so if you mean self answers you need to clarify.

Comment: @A.Lau There's *lots* of encouragement to post *high quality* Q&A.  You're quite right that we're not encouraging people to post  *low quality* Q&A.  Just because it's okay to ask and answer your own questions doesn't make it okay to ask and answer *low quality* questions.

Answer (score 7):

And when somebody asks a question, gets no help, and later finds a solution on his own -- and comes back to share it -- would you revoke the reputation earned from the question before that point?

And when somebody answers himself and later receives a better answer, would you prevent him from marking that one as accepted unless he deletes his own answer?

Things aren't broken now.  If the question is bad then downvote it, as [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297835/162102) says.  If it's meh, don't vote.  But don't assume that the question can never be good, and thus deserving of upvotes, just based on who asked it.  Judge posts on their merits, not their authors.

Comment: I would have assumed that this applies only to question and answers submitted at the same time? That would address most of your concerns... not that it makes any sense still.

Comment: @Catija maybe that was the intent (the OP didn't say), but if so, that's easily defeated.  Heck, lots of people miss the "answer your question" checkbox and end up self-answering in a separate step already.

Answer (score 1):

A self answered Q/A is just like any other Q/A posted on the site **yet harder** as generally when you ask a question you don't know the answer and you ask after having done your own research and found nothing.

Removing the up/down vote on the question would remove the user feedback of clarity, usefulness and research effort. What you don't want is people self answering *"how to i echo in PHP"* because they were too lazy to google or code dump their project which had an error in it saying *"this code doesn't work"* then a code dump answer of the fixed code saying *"this code worked"*.

A lot of the time though I think self-answered Q/A come down to usefulness of the question and answer being on the site and their clarity despite us always saying that the 2 should be voted for indeterminately of one another (of course we don't do that when we downvote answers to off-topic questions).

Using *"how to i echo in PHP"* if the answer was an alternate form of output without using `echo` your question and answer would probably get downvoted for not being clear, after all, you just posted a very round about way for `echo` for what reason? How would this be helpful to anyone?

But if you posted a question like *"how do i output from the server like echo"* and post your round-a-bout way of doing it but showing data that your method actually takes less memory and time than `echo` people might upvote them as they are the kind of people who want to save milliseconds from processing.

> And instead of displaying the question's score when browsing, display the answer instead.

Assuming you mean the answer's score (as opposed to posting an answer in that tiny space) what determines the answer when there are multiple ones? Currently when you browse the list of questions you see how many answers have been posted and if the asker as shared which answer helped them. You don't see which answers are the better ones until you see them all and we have seen cases where the accepted answer wasn't the best answer (and easily foreseeable problem is a new user to PHP accepting an answer prone to SQL Injection which is downvoted for it while another similar answer is more robust against it using prepared statements).

---

Since the Q/A in question was deleted while I was typing out a bunch of comments I'll make it into an answer here

Your question has a couple of problems wrong with it by itself.

First off, as indicated by [Walt's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297835/250962) your question relies on a third party link. Should that site go down for any reason no one would be able to understand what you're referring too.

Secondly, you ask in general how to use Datatables server side with PHP when the link you posted appears to do that already. According to a comment you made

> but the example given isn't really that clear, since they use `ssp.class.php` without really going into depth what it did. Which confused the hell out of me when I looked at it the first few times.

your real problem seems to come from the use of `ssp.class.php` and not understanding how it works in relation to the database connection. After a bit of searching I was able to find [the Github page](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php) and confirmed my assumption that `ssp.class.php` was just some custom made wrapper class to alter the returned data format, in this case it's using PDO and changing it from the the usual PDO Object to an array.

Your answer didn't help in clarifying `ssp.class.php` either because in the only PHP code you posted as an example, when the database magic would occur you just put

> ```
> // Run $statement through MySQL again, saving all $results
> ```

As such i can only assume you assumed that the user is blindly using `ssp.class.php` rather than say using [`mysqli::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [`PDOStatement::execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) both of which return results from a MySQL Database but in different formats. In fact `mysqli_*` has a [`get_result` function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) for  prepared statements and if I was to pretend I knew less than what I know, *"Run $statement through MySQL again, saving all $results"* could mean to me that I can just run `$result = $statement->get_result()` and it'll all work fine (haven't tried to see if that's the case but I doubt it given the possible return values).

Comment: Well the question links to a third party link, because it is a third party application. And yeah, I didn't really understand the whole ssp.class.php thing because it wasn't ever really explained by them. I eventually found it on github too and realised what was being passed and what not. But since I had trouble understanding it I decided to document it. It was really a self-documentation that I thought might help others who might not have instantly understood all the inner-workings, but since stackoverflow users didn't like it, I've decided to keep it to myself.

Comment: @A.Lau - Enjoy your ball, just remember, you might require somebody to share their ball.  So you keeping your ball for yourself, instead of just improving the question you asked, isn't very nice.